# Performance WHERE filter in subquery before JOIN

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have a relativly large query where I join 8 tables together some of them having a 1 to n relation. I'm wondering if it would be more efficient to filter the tables using subqueries before joining them instead of defining a larger WHERE section after ALL the joins

**Version 1 (subqueries)**

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM mdl_course WHERE idnumber REGEXP 'some regex') AS course
JOIN mdl_enrol AS enrollment ON enrollment.courseid = course.id
JOIN mdl_user_enrolments AS userEnrollment ON enrollment.Id = userEnrollment.enrolid
JOIN mdl_user AS user ON user.Id = userEnrollment.UserId
JOIN mdl_course_modules AS courseModule ON course.id = courseModule.course
JOIN mdl_modules AS module ON courseModule.module = module.id AND module.Name = 'resource'
JOIN mdl_context AS context ON context.instanceid = courseModule.id AND context.contextlevel = 70
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log WHERE component = 'mod_resource' AND action = 'viewed') AS logEntry
    ON logEntry.contextid = context.id AND logEntry.userid = user.id
```

**Version 2 (WHERE)**

```
SELECT *
FROM mdl_course AS course
JOIN mdl_enrol AS enrollment ON enrollment.courseid = course.id
JOIN mdl_user_enrolments AS userEnrollment ON enrollment.Id = userEnrollment.enrolid
JOIN mdl_user AS user ON user.Id = userEnrollment.UserId
JOIN mdl_course_modules AS courseModule ON course.id = courseModule.course
JOIN mdl_modules AS module ON courseModule.module = module.id AND module.Name = 'resource'
JOIN mdl_context AS context ON context.instanceid = courseModule.id AND context.contextlevel = 70
LEFT JOIN mdl_logstore_standard_log AS logEntry
    ON logEntry.contextid = context.id AND logEntry.userid = user.id
WHERE
    course.idnumber REGEXP 'some regex' AND
    (logEntry.component = 'mod_resource' OR logEntry.component IS NULL) AND
    (logEntry.action = 'viewed' OR logEntry.action IS NULL)
```

Would for example the regex in option 2 be executed on every joined record where course duplicates are present cause of the 1 to n relation or would this be optimized?

Comment: Seems like a question you could answer for yourself by trying it

Comment: @RiggsFolly Unfortunately not. The current dataset in the database is not large enough to show a significant difference but a growth of over 1000% is expected. Both queries (executed using DataGrip) vary between 8-36ms execution and 106-163ms fetching

Comment: A problem is only a problem when it's a problem. When it *is* a problem, then you fix it.

Comment: The first version does not seem to have `or logEntry.xxx IS NULL` ??

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT` for each.

Answer (score 0):

> filter the tables using subqueries before joining them

Probably not.  Such a subquery is likely to create a temp table with no index.  Or it may go to the extra effort to add an index dynamically.  In any case, it is *usually* more effort than it is worth.

On the other hand, it is somewhat frequently useful to do *one* "derived" table (that is, a subquery in `FROM` or `JOIN`).  Your first Select has such (with `course`, but it is probably no better than what is going on in the second Select.

`LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )` is usually a bad idea.  `LEFT` implies that you want all the rows and are not filtering on what is in that derived table.  So it may be forced to build the temp table *and* look at it last.

`OR` is a performance killer; try to avoid it.  (`OR` prevents the use of an index.)

Some of these indexes may be useful (I removed "mdl_" it is just clutter):

```
enrollment:  INDEX(courseid,  Id)
course:  INDEX(idnumber, id)
userEnrollment:  INDEX(enrolid,  UserId)
courseModule:  INDEX(course,  module, id)
context:  INDEX(contextlevel, instanceid,  id)
logEntry:  INDEX(contextid,  userid)   -- either order is OK
module:  (Name, id)
```

Do you really need `SELECT *` -- "*" probably includes lots of unnecessary columns, especially duplicated ids.  (With a specific list of needed columns, we can talk about "covering" indexes.)

**Original question** (subqueries vs joins)

The Optimizer will look at the various `WHERE` and `ON` clauses, plus derived tables and `LEFTs` to decide which table to "start" with.  It will then proceed to use NLJ (Nested Loop Join) to reach into each of the other tables, one at a time.

The optimal query has lots of filtering (`WHERE`) on one table, and it will be picked as the first.  In your case, this might be one of these:

```
context.contextlevel = 70
module.Name = 'resource'
course.idnumber REGEXP 'some regex'
```

Notice that I recommended indexes *starting* with each.  (I cannot tell which table will be picked first; it depends on the distribution of the data, *which could change from run to run*.)

I assumed that `id` was the `PRIMARY KEY` of each table, so getting to most of the tables would happen that way.

When is `LEFT` "wrong"?  When there is a `WHERE` (or equivalent `ON`) that filters the rows.  Your second Select says that that `LEFT JOIN` is really a `JOIN`.  I'm not sure if the first `SELECT` is equivalent.  When you run it, do you get NULLs for columns from logEntry?